# Puppeteer won't load images if page is loaded using setContent

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

I'm facing the problem that Puppeteer does not load resources specified with relative path (e.g. `background.png` in image `src` or css `url()`).
So that then I load content of the local file using `setContent()` the result is very different from then I do the same but using `goto(file://)`.

Apparently, then one uses 'setContent()' the page stays at 'about:page' with prevents resources with relative paths to load. I wonder if there any way to specify document location and load content from the string?

I would use `goto` but I need to pre-process the html first with Handlebar.

For now, I do the following:

```
    await page.goto(framePath);
    let content = await page.content();

    //Preprocess content here
    
    await page.setContent(processedContent);
```

but it does not feel right, and I wonder if the is a better solution.

Answer (score 6):

`setContent` internally is nothing more than this function call:

```js
await this.evaluate(html => {
  document.open();
  document.write(html);
  document.close();
}, html);
```

Basically, it writes HTML on the document already loaded. Using goto to give some location is not bad at all. You could create an `empty.html` page, and use that as your own located empty canvas.

Comment: Thanks, the same solution I use but with arbitrary empty page. Not ideal.